# How to pass data between forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application in which I want to get information from user. If user selects particular radio button then I am opening a new form in popup in which I have placed checked list box. After selecting values from check box I want to access selected value in the previous form. Below are images that can clear idea.

[image]

When user click on radio button in "Enable conent type" (as highlighted in the screen) a new form in popup is open to select values from checked list box. After selecting desired value , press "Select" button from Select Content Type form.

Now the form will be hidden but I want to get the selected values in the form "Create Lists".

### My code for Radio Button event is:

```
private void rdbEnableCtypeYes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdbEnableCtypeYes.Checked)
    {
        lblSelectContentType.Visible = true;
        frmSelectContentType selectContentType = new frmSelectContentType();
        selectContentType.rootWebUrl = rootWebUrl;
        selectContentType.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
        selectContentType.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        selectContentType.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        selectContentType.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        lblSelectContentType.Visible = false;
        cmbContentType.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

### My code for form of Select content type is:

```
public string rootWebUrl = string.Empty;
XDocument contentTypeFile = XDocument.Load(FilePaths.ContentTypesFilePath);
private void frmSelectContentType_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rootWebUrl))
    {
        if (contentTypeFile != null)
        {
            XElement xSiteCollection = contentTypeFile.Descendants(XmlElements.SiteCollection).Where(x => x.Attribute(XmlAttributes.Url).Value.Equals(rootWebUrl)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (xSiteCollection != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> xContentTypes = xSiteCollection.Descendants(XmlElements.ContentType);
                if (xContentTypes.OfType<XElement>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (XElement xContentType in xContentTypes)
                    {
                        ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                        item.Text = xContentType.Attribute(XmlAttributes.Name).Value;
                        item.Value = xContentType.Attribute(XmlAttributes.Id).Value;
                        lstContenType.Items.Add(item);                                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: `Now the form will be hidden`.... is the form just hidden or closed?  Some code to show how you are initiating this 2nd form would be helpful to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Sure sir I am editing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

Select Content Type Form

```
private List<string> _selectedItems = new List<String>();
public List<string> SelectedItem
{
    get {return _selectedItems;}
}

private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i<lst.Items.Count;i++)
    {
        if (lstContenType.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
            _selectedItems.Add(lst.Items[i].ToString());
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

---

Create List Form

```
private void rdoEnableCntType_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdoEnableCntType.Checked = true)
    {
        FrmConentType frm = new FrmConentType();        
        frm.ShowDialog();
        List<string> list = frm.SelectedItems;
        //Place your code to use selected items
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, it is working perfectly with some edit in condition. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in the Constructor of FormB. For example:

```
//Default Constructor
public FormB()
{
         InitializeComponent();
}

// Overloaded Constructor
public  FormB(string parameter1, string parameter2, string parameter3)
{
         InitializeComponent();
}
```

For example:

```
public FormB(bool RbuttonChecked)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if(RbuttonChecked)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Invoke FormB from FormA like:

```
FormB obj=new FormB(Rbtn.checked); //Invoking the overloaded constructor
obj.Show();
```

Comment: I want to access the selected items from Select Content Type form to Create Lists form.
i.e. First Create Lists form is opened then the form "Select Content Type" is opened after selecting values from checked box list in "Select Content Types" form I want to access them in "Create Lists".

Answer (score 0):

You can defined a list in the main form to store items user selected in "Select Content Type" windows. When user have finished the window "Select Content Type", you add selected items to the variable.

In Form "Create List" class:

```
public List<ContentType> selectedContentTypes = new List<ContentType>();
```

When user press "Select" button in form "Select Content Type", add items to the variable:

```
// For each selected items in the listbxo {
    frmCreateList.selectedContentTypes.Items.Add(itemId);
// }
```

If you can post your source code, it would be easier to help.